# I am trying to create a macro which pulls the rating and total reviews from IMDB.com into an excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of movies in a sheet that spans from A2:A966 and I'm trying to get the process to work however my code gets a run time error 91. Right now it asks for a name for a movie in the form of an input box (pulled from as many resources as I could but the tutorial which I found most useful used an input box) but ideally it would just run through the list of movies in the A2:A966 and pull the data for the ratings into B2:966 and total ratings into C2:C966

```
Sub test()
    Dim eRow As Long
    Dim ele As Object
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    RowCount = 1
    sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "IMDB Rating"
    sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Total Reviews"
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'strSearch = Range("A2")
    moviename = InputBox("Enter movie name")

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.imdb.com/"

        Do While .Busy Or _
          .readystate <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set nam = .document.getElementsByName("navbar-query")
        nam.Item(0).Value = moviename

        .document.getElementsByID("navbar-submit-button").Click
        .document.getElementsByID("result_text").Click

        Do While .Busy Or _
          .readystate <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        For Each ele In .document.all
            Select Case ele.classname
                Case "Result"
                    RowCount = RowCount + 1
                Case "ratingValue"
                    sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
                Case "ratingCount"
                    sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
            End Select
        Next ele
    End With

    Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using an input, you could declare `A2:A966` a range, or even create an array of that range, and loop through the search setting a new cell each time.

Comment: Before performing the reverse search, you need to make sure your script has the ability of pulling data from that site @John Gendi. That is what I've fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways you can achieve that. Here is one of them. Give it a go:

```
Sub imd_data()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, ele As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.imdb.com/"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    html.getElementById("navbar-query").Value = "Blood Diamond"
    html.getElementById("navbar-submit-button").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    html.getElementsByClassName("result_text")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    For Each ele In html.getElementsByClassName("imdbRating")
        With ele.getElementsByClassName("ratingValue")
            If .Length Then r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With ele.getElementsByClassName("small")
            If .Length Then Cells(r, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next ele

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

```
8.0/10  434,144
```

Comment: Btw, mind the `s` of `.getElementsByID` you used in your script. ID is always used as singular.

Comment: This is very helpful, I played around with it but am struggling to be able to get the output to be entered into a specific cell on my excel sheet i'll post my code as an answer to show you what I've modified

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub imd_data()


 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, ele As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.google.com/"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
        Set sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    html.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = sht.Range("A2") & " IMDB"
    html.getElementById("btnK").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    html.getElementsByClassName("rc")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    For Each ele In html.getElementsByClassName("imdbRating")
        With ele.getElementsByClassName("ratingValue")
            'If .Length Then r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
            sht.Range("B2") = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With ele.getElementsByClassName("small")
            'If .Length Then Cells(r, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
             sht.Range("C2") = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next ele

    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have used this `http://www.google.com/` link unintentionally within your script, right?

Comment: No i switched to google for the initial search because IMDB website is very heavy to navigate through